# Terraform map lookup not working in newer version (1.3.0)

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm, hashicorp

I have older version of Terraform in a sandbox environment Terraform version: 0.14.9 in which Terraform map lookup is working as expecting but the same code is not working in  Terraform version: 1.3.0.

```
variable "location-code" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
    eastus = "eus1"
    westus = "wus1"
  }
}
variable "location" {
  description = "Location where the resource need to create - eus1, wus1 etc"
  type        = string
  default     = "eastus"
}
locals {
  formatted_name = "${lookup(var.location-code, var.location, "default")}${var.appenv}${var.appname}"}
```

When I provide location variable as **eastus** I am expecting lookup function works the same & replaces with eus1, but this is not working as expected. Could someone share some help with this. TIA.

This works in older version as expected but just with newer version its not working

Comment: "code is not working" - is not specific. What EXACTLY is happening? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because of the syntax of your local block. Ending `}` in the same line as the local values. I have tried exact same variable and it seems to be working by just adding a new line before the `}` ending or making the local definition in one line.

When I used exactly your code snippet I got this error message

```bash
  random_local_tests git:(main) ✗ tf plan                                                                                                      <aws:sre>
╷
│ Error: Missing newline after argument
│ 
│   on random_locals.tf line 27, in locals:
│   27:   formatted_name = "${lookup(var.location-code, var.location, "default")}${var.appenv}${var.appname}"}
│ 
│ An argument definition must end with a newline.
```

**What has worked to fix this:**

```
locals {
  formatted_name = "${lookup(var.location-code, var.location, "default")}${var.appenv}${var.appname}"
}

variable "location-code" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
    eastus = "eus1"
    westus = "wus1"
  }
}
variable "location" {
  description = "Location where the resource need to create - eus1, wus1 etc"
  type        = string
  default     = "eastus"
}
variable "appenv" {
  type    = string
  default = "dev"
}

variable "appname" {
  type    = string
  default = "stackoverflow"
}

output "formatted_name" {
  value = local.formatted_name
}
```

**Output With Teraform v1.3.5:**

```bash
➜  random_local_tests git:(main) ✗ tf version                                                                                                   <aws:sre>
Terraform v1.3.5
on darwin_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.47.0

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 1.3.7. You can update by downloading from https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html
➜  random_local_tests git:(main) ✗ tf plan                                                                                                      <aws:sre>

Changes to Outputs:
  + formatted_name = "eus1devstackoverflow"

You can apply this plan to save these new output values to the Terraform state, without changing any real infrastructure.

─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Note: You didn't use the -out option to save this plan, so Terraform can't guarantee to take exactly these actions if you run "terraform apply" now.
```

As a side note, this would also work but is not recommended as not readable when using multiple local values.

```
locals { formatted_name = "${lookup(var.location-code, var.location, "default")}${var.appenv}${var.appname}" }
```